# Woes with std::shared_ptr<T>.use_counter()

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, reference-counting

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count states:

> In multithreaded environment, the value returned by use_count is approximate (typical implementations use a memory_order_relaxed load)

But does this mean that `use_count()` is totally useless in a multi-threaded environment?

Consider the following example, where the `Circular` class implements a circular buffer of `std::shared_ptr<int>`.

One method is supplied to users - `get()`, which checks whether the reference count of the `next` element in the `std::array<std::shared_ptr<int>>` is greater than 1 (which we don't want, since it means that it's being held by a user which previously called `get()`).

If it's `<= 1`, a copy of the `std::shared_ptr<int>` is returned to the user.

In this case, the users are two threads which do nothing at all except love to call `get()` on the circular buffer - that's their purpose in life.

What happens in practice when I execute the program is that it runs for a few cycles (tested by adding a `counter` to the circular buffer class), after which it throws the exception, complaining that the reference counter for the next element is `> 1`.

Is this a result of the statement that the value returned by `use_count()` is approximate in a multi-threaded environment?

Is it possible to adjust the underlying mechanism to make it, uh, deterministic and behave as I would have liked it to behave?

If my thinking is correct - `use_count()` (or rather the real number of users) of the `next` element should never EVER increase above 1 when inside the `get()` function of `Circular`, since there are only two consumers, and every time a thread calls `get()`, it's already released its old (copied) `std::shared_ptr<int>` (which in turn means that the remaining `std::shared_ptr<int>` residing in `Circular::ints_` should have a reference count of only 1).

```
#include <mutex>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <thread>

class Circular {
    public:
      Circular() {
          for (auto& i : ints_) { i = std::make_shared<int>(0); }
      }

      std::shared_ptr<int> get() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(guard_);
        index_ = index_ % 2;  // Re-set the index pointer.

        if (ints_.at(index_).use_count() > 1) {
          // This shouldn't happen - right? (but it does)
          std::string excp = std::string("OOPSIE: ") + std::to_string(index_) + " " + std::to_string(ints_.at(index_).use_count());
          throw std::logic_error(excp);
        }

        return ints_.at(index_++);
      }

    private:
        std::mutex                          guard_;
        unsigned int                        index_{0};
        std::array<std::shared_ptr<int>, 2> ints_;
};

Circular circ;
void func() {
    do {
      auto scoped_shared_int_pointer{circ.get()};
    }while(1);
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(func), t2(func);

  t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

Comment: What reasoning can you provide for your expectation that the next element is not *supposed* to be held any more?

Comment: Since the copy of the 'original' std::shared_ptr<int> should be destroyed after 'auto scoped_shared_int_pointer{circ.get()};, thus decreasing the reference counter from 2 to 1.

Comment: `use_count` is for debugging only and shouldn't be used. If you want to know when nobody else has a reference to a pointer any more just let the shared pointer die and use a custom deleter to detect that and do whatever you need to do with the now unused pointer

Comment: getting  `use_count` is separate from testing the value you got and making a decision. Getting the count may be sufficiently protected, but by the time you look at the value you got, it may have been invalidated. You need to protect the whole transacion.

Comment: @user4581301 - Yes, I know that - the rationale behind the construction of the example was to illustrate a scenario in which two threads need to share a finite pool of data of a particular type, and be certain that only one of the threads operate on a single element from the pool at a time.
The utilization of a circular buffer with an index counter is one way to achieve this - the index counting/resetting is protected by the lock guard within the get() method. The idea would be to size the Circular buffer with the number of threads, thus protecting the system against cross-thread memory use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use_count` is for debugging only and shouldn't be used. If you want to know when nobody else has a reference to a pointer any more just let the shared pointer die and use a custom deleter to detect that and do whatever you need to do with the now unused pointer.

This is an example of how you might implement this in your code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Circular {
public:
  Circular() {
    size_t index = 0;
    for (auto& i : ints_)
    {
      i = 0;
      unused_.push_back(index++);
    }
  }

  std::shared_ptr<int> get() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(guard_);

    if (unused_.empty())
    {
      throw std::logic_error("OOPSIE: none left");
    }
    size_t index = unused_.back();
    unused_.pop_back();
    return std::shared_ptr<int>(&ints_[index], [this, index](int*) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(guard_);
      unused_.push_back(index);
    });
  }

private:
  std::mutex guard_;
  std::vector<size_t> unused_;
  std::array<int, 2> ints_;
};

Circular circ;
void func() {
  do {
    auto scoped_shared_int_pointer{ circ.get() };
  } while (1);
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(func), t2(func);

  t1.join(); t2.join();
}
```

A list of unused indexes is kept, when the shared pointer is destroyed the custom deleter returns the index back to the list of unused indexes ready to be used in the next call to `get`.

Comment: Great! Apart from utilizing use_count, there was also an algorithmic error in the implementation of the 'get()' function which @Dave-S mentioned, in that I'd made an implicit assumption regarding the time-order of events.

Comment: Yep, this method avoids that problem and will scale to any number of threads, the order of execution doesn't matter

Comment: Although, it should probably be:

`return std::shared_ptr<int>(ints_.at(index).get(), [this, index](int*) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(guard_); 
            free_.push_back(index);
        });`

Comment: `ints_` is just an array of `int` in my example, not `shared_ptr` (there's no need for them to be pointers and you'll probably get better performance from them being in a contiguous array)

Comment: Ah, I see that now - I was actually thinking about a more involved example in which the array doesn't actually store just shared pointers to integers, but shared pointers to (much) larger data structures.

Comment: The same still applies, you'd be better off using a contiguous array than separate heap allocated pointers, you aren't going to be moving or copying them anywhere so you don't need them to be pointers

Comment: I've realized there's an unfortunate memory issue with the above example... The 'this' class instance might no longer exist when the destructor for the shared pointer executes... :)

Comment: @ChrisRajula just store instances of `Circular` and in the custom deleter use `shared_from_this` to capture a copy of the `Circular` `shared_ptr`. e.g https://godbolt.org/z/Td6cWfWj7

Answer (score 5):

While `use_count` is fraught with problems, the core issue right now is outside of that logic.

Assume thread `t1` takes the `shared_ptr` at index 0, and then `t2` runs its loop twice before `t1` finishes its first loop iteration.  `t2` will obtain the `shared_ptr` at index 1, release it, and then attempt to acquire the `shared_ptr` at index 0, and will hit your failure condition, since `t1` is just running behind.

Now, that said, in a broader context, it's not particularly safe, as if a user creates a `weak_ptr`, it's entirely possible for the `use_count` to go from 1 to 2 without passing through this function.  In this simple example, it would work to have it loop through the index array until it finds the free shared pointer.

Comment: The other pointer is held within the std::array<std::shared_ptr<int>, 2>, which is internal to Circular, i.e. the 'real' reference count on each std::shared_ptr<int> should always be at least 1 since there's always one such shared pointer being held internally in the std::array.

Comment: @ChrisRajula Yep, had a brain fart it seems.